# RXJS ANGULAR - Observable still called after takeWhile operator is resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am storing data in the session storage with an expiry date :

```
private saveSessionData<T>(key: string, value: T) {
    const item = {
      value: value,
      expiry: Date.now() + 10 * 60000 // 10 minutes from now
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
  }
```

I have an other function to access those data, that will return null if the data I try to access is expired :

```
private async getSessionData<T>(key: string): Promise<T | null> {
    const itemStr = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    const item = JSON.parse(itemStr);
    if (Date.now() > item.expiry) {
      console.log('CONSOLE NULL');
      await this.alertService('OBJ EXPIRED');
      return null;
    }
    return item.value;
  }
```

I access those data like that :

```
getMyObj$ (): Observable<MyObj| null> {
    return from(this.getSessionData<MyObj>(this._myObj))
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(myObj => myObj != null),
        tap(x => console.log('getting my Obj')
    );
  }
```

In my View, I'm using the | async to show `myObj` with a two way data binding :

```
<div *ngIf="!!(getMyObj$ | async) as obj">
  <div>{{ obj }}</div>
</div>
```

My thought would be that my console show me the `getting my Obj` again and again until the expiry date is overdue, and then to see the alert message : `OBJ EXPIRED` with the console message `CONSOLE NULL` once.
But currently, after the `getting my Obj` message, I have infinite `CONSOLE NULL` messages (that makes my browser crash) and the alert event is never shown.

Any one got any idea ? I have no idea what could makes that crash like that.

Comment: Blind guess, try with `takeWhile(myObj => !!myObj)`. Maybe it's undefined, but `undefined` and `null` are not the same thing, so the condition turns out as being true despite myObj being undefined? Worth a shot

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm facing the same issue with `takeWhile(myObj => !!myObj)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of angular change detection, causing it to repeatedly call that method and subscribe to a new observable each time. You should instead create the observable once and share it:

```js
this.getMyObj$ = 
  interval(1000).pipe(
    concatMap(() => this.getSessionData<MyObj>(this._myObj)),
    takeWhile(myObj => myObj != null),
    tap(x => console.log('getting my Obj'),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, the interval was the answer !!!!